# Unhandled Exception: type 'Uint8List' is not a subtype of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Dio to try and fetch a stream of an image stored in the database as a binary. Whenever I try to fetch the image from Flutter I end up with the error

> Unhandled Exception: type 'Uint8List' is not a subtype of type 'int'

The current setup stream converts the binary data to a List(Uint8List), but I need it to be List(int)

I will appreciate any help

What I have done so far

```
var imageBinary = await Dio().get(userUri + "/" + id.toString(), options: Options(headers: {"authorization": "Bearer $token"}, responseType: ResponseType.stream));
    var temp = await imageBinary.data.stream.toList();
    img = List.from(temp);
    photo = Image.memory(img);
```

Comment: Which type of data is returned by browsing your link `userUri + "/" + id.toString()` ?

Answer (score 0):

hm it seems like this `asTypedList` should do it:

docs:
Creates a typed list view backed by memory in the address space.
The returned view will allow access to the memory range from address to address + length.
The user has to ensure the memory range is accessible while using the returned list.
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.6.0/dart-ffi/Uint8Pointer/asTypedList.html

```
external Uint8List asTypedList(int length);
```

Comment: where should I place this?

Answer (score 0):

`List<Uint8List>` is basically `List<List<int>>`, so convert it into `List<int>` you will have to flatten it. The following snippet should do it.

```dart
  var img = List.from(temp).expand((i) => i).toList();
```

But I think It's better to use `ReponseType.bytes` in your particular scenario. It's an opinion because you are awaiting the stream in the next line you started fetching it. Maybe, the code you shared is just for this question, and in reality, you may be using streams for good reason. but I wanted to mention this.

If you wanna use `ResponseType.bytes`:

```dart
var imageBinary = await Dio().get(userUri + "/" + id.toString(), options: Options(headers: {"authorization": "Bearer $token"}, responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
var img = imageBinary.data; // this will be UintList8 (or in other words List<int>
var photo = Image.memory(img);
```

Comment: can show me how to use `ReponseType.bytes` as using `img = List.from(temp).expand((i) => i).toList()` throws an error  `Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'`

Comment: @blackbird updated the answer with the code.